# Cycle-cancelling algorithm, Minimum cost flow

Tags: network-flow

I am studying the cycle cancelling algorithm for the minimum cost flow problem, and I can not understand the proof of the following:

If there no negative cost cycles then you have a minimum cost flow. The other direction is easy but I am stuck with this one.

If you want to get a smaller cost with an augmentation on the residual graph then it's impossible because you don't have negative cycles

**But**

Wouldn't it be possible to choose a cycle in the residual graph augment the cycle's flow and create negative cycles again ? which are bigger than what cost you increased in the augmentation so the net result would be a smaller cost.

Answer (score 1):

It could have something to do with the amount of flow you redirect when you perform augmentation $\gamma$ along a positive cycle $\epsilon$.

Since you are assuming the creation of negative cycles, it means that you have created at least one new negative cost arc(the new negative arcs in residual graph $G(x')$ are the result of pushing flow on arcs in $G$ which had no flow assigned in flow $x$).

The residual capacity of those new negative arcs is equal to the flow redirected with $\gamma$.

This gives you an upperbound on the amount of flow you can redirect in any new negative cycle.

It can be shown too that the cost of any negative cycle, $\eta$, created with augmentation $\gamma$, is bound to be less or equal, in absolute value, to the cost of $\epsilon$. (Consider the subset of arcs in $\epsilon$ that created the negative cost arcs which are used in $\eta$).